# removing item from list of weak_ptrs

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a list of weak_ptrs that I'm using to keep track of objects. At a certain point, I would like to remove an item from the list given a shared_ptr or a weak_ptr.

```
#include <list>

int main()
{
typedef std::list< std::weak_ptr<int> > intList;

std::shared_ptr<int> sp(new int(5));
std::weak_ptr<int> wp(sp);

intList myList;
myList.push_back(sp);

//myList.remove(sp);
//myList.remove(wp);
}
```

However, when I uncomment the above lines, the program won't build:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\list(1194): error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::tr1::weak_ptr<_Ty>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

How do I remove an item from the list given a shared_ptr or a weak_ptr?

Answer (score 8):

There is no operator== for weak pointers. You could compare the shared_ptrs your weak_ptrs point to.
E.g like this.

```
myList.remove_if([wp](std::weak_ptr<int> p){
    std::shared_ptr<int> swp = wp.lock();
    std::shared_ptr<int> sp = p.lock();
    if(swp && sp)
        return swp == sp;
    return false;
});
```

Comment: There's an `owner_before`, though, which implements a partial order.So you could also write the lambda as `[wp](std::weak_ptr<int> p){ return !(p.owner_before(wp) || wp.owner_before(p));` - no lock needed. Also, in your code I think you missed the `swp==sp==0` case.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without a lambda? I'll be removing items in a lot of different places. I see that the remove_if predicate is called on each element individually but I'll need to compare 2 pointers like you have above.

Comment: @user987280 Sure you can use a functor or a free function instead of a lambda. But what exactly is the problem that the predicate gets called for each element?